# How to use router.createUrlTree in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm just started learning Angular, and making a simple application. I'm trying to do routing and call some API like this:

```
GET /products
GET /products?categoryId=1&minPrice=20&maxPrice=50
```

This is how my service method looking:

```
getAllProducts(categoryId?: number, minPrice?: number, maxPrice?: number): Observable<Product[]> {
const tree = this.router.createUrlTree([], {
    queryParams: {
      categoryId: categoryId,
      minPrice: minPrice,
      maxPrice: maxPrice
    }
  });

return this.http.get<Product[]>(environment.baseURL + this.serializer.serialize(tree));
}
```

I call it from one component products.main.component. Router creates proper URL, like this (when no parameters provided):

```
baseURL/products
```

But, products.main.component has two routes in app-routing.module.ts file:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsMainComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: ProductsMainComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products/add',
    component: AddProductComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'products/edit/:id',
    component: EditProductComponent
  }
];
```

When component calls service from 'products' path everything is fine. But when component calls service from default path router generates URL like this:

```
baseURL/
```

If I make this:

```
return this.http.get<Product[]>(environment.baseURL + '/products' +this.serializer.serialize(tree));
```

Default path works fine but 'products' path breaks like this:

```
baseURL/products/products
```

How to properly use router.createUrlTree?

Comment: Why are you calling your own route ??? `http.get` is for calling your backend, not your own app.

Comment: I'm not calling my own route. I use router.createUrlTree to automatically construct URL (depending on parameters categoryId, minPrice, maxPrice) for API call. Something like this: baseURL/products?categoryId=1&minPrice=20

Comment: `createUrlTree` is meant to be used for navigation within the app.

Comment: I'm not saying that I did right. I just wanted automatically generate "complex" URLs with parameters regardless if they are null or not. Is there a better way?

Comment: You probably want the native `URLSearchParams`

Comment: I tried URLSearchParams, and it produced this string: ```categoryId=1&minPrice=undefined&maxPrice=undefined``` Is it possible to not include null or undefined parameters in the result string?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. Instead of using router I used HttpParams. I think it's more elegant solution than a bunch of if statements. Here is my new service method: (**>= ES 2017**)

```
getAllProducts(filter?: object): Observable<Product[]> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  Object.entries(filter ?? {}).forEach(
      ([key, value]) => value && (params = params.append(key, value))
  );
  return this.http.get<Product[]>(environment.baseURL + ApiPaths.Products, {params});
}
```